# Does an iOS app compiled for armv7 run on iPad Air, iPhone 5S, etc. (armv8 devices)?

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7

I'm making an iPhone/iPad app that includes a library that's only compiled for architecture `armv7`. That includes all iOS devices prior to the iPad Air, iPhone 5C/S and iPad Mini gen 2. Those devices have a `armv8-a` architecture. If I compile my app for `armv7` (with `Valid Architectures` set to "armv7"), will the app run on the `armv8` devices too? And what about 64-bit?

It would make sense that apps from the iOS 6 era, will still run on those newer devices. I know that for instance, when compiling for `armv7`, your app will still run on the iPhone 5's `armv7` because it's a subset.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Reinder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, theorically you could even compile against armv6 and it will work on all the future devices.

[A nice infograpich about mobile Apple architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21422550/1293167)

*Btw "armv8" is called arm64*